# Oracle SELF JOIN Give suggestion

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem, I don’t know how to solve it! Please help me.

```
date                　text     ID        Action
================　　 ====== 　 ======  ======
2020-11-24 15:34:09  A12345    B_AAAA   Cleared
2020-11-24 15:33:40  A56789  　C_AAAA    Occured
2020-11-24 15:33:09  A12345 　 B_AAAA    Occured
2020-11-24 15:32:09  A45678  　A_AAAA    Cleared
2020-11-24 15:31:09  A45678  　A_AAAA    Occured
```

Find all the data in Table, and compare the text, id, and match.

[Action.Occured] will continue to search down [Action.Cleared].
If there is a corresponding one, it will not be displayed.

example:

```
2020-11-24 15:31:09 　A45678  　A_AAAA    Occured
2020-11-24 15:32:09 　A45678  　A_AAAA    Cleared
```

These two pens will correspond to each other and will not be displayed.

```
2020-11-24 15:33:09 　A12345 　 B_AAAA    Occured
2020-11-24 15:34:09 　A12345  　B_AAAA    Cleared
```

These two pens will correspond to each other and will not be displayed.

The final data will only be :

```
2020-11-24 15:33:40 　A56789  　C_AAAA    Occured
```

Why only this data is displayed, because he did not find the corresponding [Cleared]

Comment: Your examples are not clear.  It seems like you just want `where id = 'B_AAAA'` and so on.

Comment: You need to clarify several things. First: Can the "action" only be 'Occurred' (notice the correct spelling) or 'Cleared', or can it be something else? In particular, can it be `null`? If so, how do you handle? Second: can Occurred and Cleared appear with the exact same timestamp? And if so, how to handle? Third: Can Cleared appear **before** Occurred - and if so, how to handle? Finally, can either Occurred or Cleared (or both!) appear more than once, for the same ID and same text - and if so, how to handle?

Comment: My simple explanation:occurred = an error has occurred
Cleared = The error has been resolved
If an error occurs, it must be resolved, if it is not resolved, an error will be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

I would use exists logic which checks that one member of the pair does not have a corresponding member:

```sql
SELECT "date", text, ID, Action
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE Action = 'Occured' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                  WHERE t2.text = t1.text AND t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.Action = 'Cleared');
```

This answer assumes that `Cleared` and `Occured` are the only two possible actions.  If not, then the above logic would have to be changed to something more complex.

Comment: My simple explanation:
occurred = an error has occurred
Cleared = The error has been resolved
If an error occurs, it must be resolved, if it is not resolved, an error will be displayed.

Comment: @ChiaWei Check my updated answer per your latest logic.

Answer (score 0):

Using `lag()` could be one option

```
select date,text,id,action from
(
select *,lag(Action) over(partition by text,id order by date) as prev_action
from tablename 
)A where action<>coalesce(prev_action,'')
```